# Custom background colour won't override Bootstrap 5.3's

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

After updating to Bootstrap to 5.3.1, two custom background colours won't override the colours defined by Bootstrap. Not even with `!important` added. They did override as expected before updating.

My styles are:

```
table tr.shaded {
    background-color:#e1e9ff !important;
}
table tr.highlight {
    background-color:#eaeaf0 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Bootstrap 5.3.1 has (in tables.scss:5):

```
.table {
    ...
    --bs-table-bg: var(--bs-body-bg);
    ...
}
```

My CSS file is loaded after the Bootstrap file.

If I untick the above property in Firefox's inspector, my background colour is displayed.

I did read other threads with similar issues: there are no typos in my CSS and it was working fine before the update. I hadn't even added `!important` as above. The Bootstrap files are loaded locally; the entire website is available on localhost only – ifthat's relevant.

Tested in Firefox and in Chrome, after full reload (Ctrl+Shift+R).

Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT: Adding the HTML code.

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-12 table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm table-borderless list">
        <thead>
            <tr class="shaded text-center align-middle">
                <th width="25">ID</th>
                <th>Project name</th>
                <th>Languages</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Completed</th>
                <th><strong>Profit</strong></th>
                <th>Paid?</th>
                <th>Invoice</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't provide a code snippet, so can't see what's in your html code and what classes you're applying where, but your CSS is referencing the table tag while Bootstrap's CSS is referencing a class selector (`table` vs. `.table``). That might be why your classes aren't overriding Bootstrap's.

Comment: @RichDeBourke, I've added the HTML code to my question. I do not know how to add a code snippet, sorry. I know about the difference you mention, which is what makes it all the more puzzling. The table has the `.table` class and it is though this that my own `.shaded` class is overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap sets the background color for the table elements using the selector `.table > :not(caption) > * > *`. Your selector `table tr.shaded` is less specific, so it won’t override Bootstrap’s selector (even with `!important`).

I think you can achieve what you’re looking for by applying the background color to the `th` element, rather than the `tr` element.

```css
tr.shaded th {
    background-color:#e1e9ff;
}
tr.highlight th {
    background-color:#eaeaf0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-10 col-sm-12 table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm table-borderless list">
        <thead>
            <tr class="shaded text-center align-middle">
                <th width="25">ID</th>
                <th>Project name</th>
                <th>Languages</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Completed</th>
                <th><strong>Profit</strong></th>
                <th>Paid?</th>
                <th>Invoice</th>
            </tr>
            <tr class="highlight text-center align-middle">
                <th width="25">ID</th>
                <th>Project name</th>
                <th>Languages</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Completed</th>
                <th><strong>Profit</strong></th>
                <th>Paid?</th>
                <th>Invoice</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. What I don't understand is why my code worked all this time in Bootstrap 4 and then Bootstrap 5.1 – until I upgraded to 5.3.1.